# How to assign value to field in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am using RailsAdmin gem and I have some virtual attributes in model. I made input fields in rails_admin.rb initializer for that attributes like this:

```
  field :name, :string do
    formatted_value do
      "123123213213"
    end
    read_only false
  end
```

I tried to assign value to field like this but nothing is happening. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign default value then

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize do
    if new_record?
      self.name ||= '123123213213' 
    end
  end
end
```

[Check this](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/How-to-set-default-values)

Comment: what if I want `self.email` to be `self.name + '@domain.com'` and I want it to  update as user types in the frontend?

Comment: `self.email ||= self.name + '@domain.com'` works? And will it update continuously as user types his name?